# MessageResource.ErrorCode meaning?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Trying to find (detailed) documentation for the `MessageResource` class; specifically what the values of the property `ErrorCode` mean.  All I can find is [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-csharp/5.13.5/class_twilio_1_1_rest_1_1_api_1_1_v2010_1_1_account_1_1_message_resource.html#ae65dc202ff4914ec9c737815aa1cb361), but that gives only the most cursory info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error codes are located on [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors)

More detailed descriptions of return values of `ErrorCode`, `ErrorMessage`, etc are on [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource)